# Relation between $SO\left(1,3\right)$ and $SU\left(2\right)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I've seen it claimed in physics classes that there is an isomorphism of Lie algebras 
$$\mathfrak{so}\left(1,3\right)\cong \mathfrak{su}\left(2\right)\oplus\mathfrak{su}\left(2\right)$$
However, the argument used relied on taking complex linear combinations of a basis for $\mathfrak{so}\left(1,3\right)$ so that the resulting basis contained two copies of $\mathfrak{su}\left(2\right)$.

Namely, there is a basis for $\mathfrak{so}\left(1,3\right)$ given by $\left\{J_1,J_2,J_3,K_1,K_2,K_3\right\}$ with 
$$\left[J_i,J_j\right]=\sum _{k=1}^3\varepsilon _{ijk}J_k$$
$$\left[K_i,K_j\right]=\sum _{k=1}^3\varepsilon _{ijk}J_k$$
$$\left[J_i,K_j\right]=\sum _{k=1}^3\varepsilon _{ijk}K_k$$
The new elements $J_i^{\pm}=J_i\pm iK_i$ then have the commutation relations of two copies of $\mathfrak{su}\left(2\right)$.

The problem I have with this derivation is that $\mathfrak{so}\left(1,3\right)$ and $\mathfrak{su}\left(2\right)$ are real Lie algebras. So, taking complex linear combinations doesn't really make sense.

Is the stated result true?

Comment: Nope, this isomorphism is false. The Lie algebra $so(1,3)$ is noncompact (it has indefinite Killing form) while $su(2)\oplus su(2)$ is compact. Another way to see that such an isomorphism does not exist is to observe that $so(1,3)$ is simple while $su(2)\oplus su(2)$ is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relationship of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ to $\mathfrak{su}(2)\oplus\mathfrak{su}(2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229248/relationship-of-mathfrakso1-3-to-mathfraksu2-oplus-mathfraksu2?rq=1).

Comment: Looks unlikely to be. Your RHS is the Lie algebra of a compact Lie group, your LHS is the Lie algebra of a non-compact Lie group.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Which theorem are you using to go from topological properties of the group to properties of its Lie algebra?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley: Every finite-dimensional real Lie algebra is isomorphic to the Lie algebra of a unique (up to a continuous isomorphism) simply-connected real Lie group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, what then is the signature of the Killing form in the case of $\mathfrak{so}\left(1,3\right)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, Can you tell me which are the simply connected Lie groups in either case to show the compactness vs non-compactness?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley: The signature is $(3,3)$: The maximal compact subalgebra in $o(3,1)$ is $o(3)$ contributes a maximal negative subspace of the Killing form.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, Thanks for the info. Any chance you could post a more step by step explanation if you have time? It is not clear to me that $\mathfrak{o}\left(n\right)$ has a +ve definite Killing form for instance, I think the rest I can then get.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37323/proof-that-lie-group-with-finite-centre-is-compact-if-and-only-if-its-killing-fo?rq=1

Comment: It's the **complexifications** of those Lie algebras which are isomorphic, and apparently many sources are too sloppy to write this, and so every couple of weeks somebody asks about this here. Besides @DietrichBurde's link, cf. for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/639749/96384 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1109369/96384.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathfrak{so}(1, 3)$, while a real Lie algebra, happens to be isomorphic as a real Lie algebra to the complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$. This Lie algebra is the [complexification](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Complexification_of_a_Lie_algebra) of the real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, so we have a direct sum decomposition

$$\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus i \mathfrak{su}(2)$$

but this is *not* a Lie algebra direct sum; the factor $i \mathfrak{su}(2)$ isn't closed under Lie bracket. It is just a way of expressing that $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ is the complexification of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

Comment: So, $\mathfrak{so}\left(1,3\right)\cong \mathfrak{su}\left(2\right)\otimes \mathbb{C}$ as real Lie algebras?

Comment: @Joshua: yes, that's right.